Searching the Spice model of the Liteon optocoupler LTV-817-A
I start learning simulation with "Altium Designer". Unfortunately, i did not find the spice model for the Liteon optocoupler "LTV-817-A".
Do you know where i can find it or a very similar component.
Thank you.

Any other suggestions for a starter is welcome.

You might have to use the datasheet to create your own model. What aspect(s)/behavior(s) of the optocoupler are you trying to look at in your simulation?

Is it so much different from the PC817? https://www.findchips.com/compare/LTV-817--vs--PC817 or is it a replacement for that part?
